# Javascript & Cordova : sound not works

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio

This very simple code in JavaScript is not working in Cordova, any ideas why?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <style>
        nav#nav1{margin-top: 24px;}
        nav#nav1 > a{ background:#B9E1FF; color:#000; padding:10px; text-decoration:none; border-radius:5px; font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif; }
        nav#nav1 > a:hover{ background: #BBEA00; }
        nav#nav1 > a:active{ background: #EEFFA8; }
    </style>
    <script>
        var bleep = new Audio();
        bleep.src = 'bleep.mp3';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <nav id="nav1">
            <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">Home</a>
            <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">About Us</a>
            <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">Services</a>
            <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">Contact</a>
        </nav>
</div>
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please link the plugin you are using for the Audio() object.

The Cordova documentation uses "Media" :
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/

If you use this plugin you should have a better result!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var bleep = new Audio("proper_path/bleep.mp3");
```

Also, you can also try `new Media` not `new Audio`, where there is a plugin for it. 
Another common mistake is forgetting to add the cordova javascript file on top of the file.